# ng-change triggered by ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ng-change` on a bunch of form fields in a site I'm building. When I change page using ui-router, the ng-change function is triggered for every single field on the form after `stateChangeSuccess`.

Is this normal - or have I broken something significant?

Comment: That's not normal. Can you post the appropriate code in a plunker?

Comment: It's too huge! If its not normal I'll start looking in other places.